# Joomla when changing the headerlogo in beez3 template the image isn't fit to the headerlogo

Tags: css, image, joomla, header

I have Joomla 3.7.
I have replaced the file personal2.png in /templates/beez3/images/personal/personal2.png
to another image with the same resolution ( 1060X288 ).
The Image Logo changed but the image isn't fit, I mean the Image is with another size (more bigger).

I wanna inherit the default CSS and I want the image to fit to the logo header size and to be resized when the screen browser is smaller ( because when I smaller the windows the image is not showing very well and I lost some of it.
( I mean I want it responsive to the size of the window ).

I appreciate any help.
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use bootstrap, it will give you the power of automatically adjusting the layout according to the size of your UI.

Comment: I think joomla is linked to bootstrap.
but how can I make this logo header in bootstrap looking good ?
what should I write and how ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with joomla, I suggested about bootstrap because you didn't mention whether you are using it or not.

Comment: Can you share a link to site?

Comment: I am not uploaded the site right yet.. but it's a regular joomla... I just changed the logo header ( personal2.png ) to another image with the same name and the same resolution... but the image isn't showing very well... I mean it's not fitted to the logo header. it's more bigger and not fitted